# Different values of the distance between the axis

Tags: plot, flot

I need to plot y axis de120 to -10, with separation of 10 by appointment. And the x-axis between 0 and 160000.

The values ​​on the axis are 125, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 12000, 16000.

My problem is on the x axis, which takes the configuration:

First axis value: 0.3 cm, from the zero 
Second value axis: 1.3 cm, from the zeros 
Third value axis: 2.3 cm, from the zeros 
Other values​​, with 0.5 cm more than the previous value.

This helps to understand the result you expect. 
How should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom tickGenerator and tickFormatter functions, as shown in the [Customizing the Axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) section of the docs and the [Basic Options](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-options/) example.